# renaming IDs in dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, rename

I'm trying to rename two ID columns in the nested dataframe below into numeric characters. I've tried doing it using the code below:

Original data frame is A:

```
x_1 <- c("A1", "A1","A1", "B10", "B10", "B10","B10", "B500", "C100", "C100", "C100", "D40", "G100", "G100")

y_1 <- c(rep("M", 8), rep("O", 6))  

z_1 <- c(1.1, 1.4, 1.6, -1.0, -2.2, 3, 2.3, 2.0, -3.4, -4.1, 2, 2, 2.4, -3.5)


A <- data.frame(x_1, z_1, y_1)
```

Desired data frame is B:

```
y_3 <- factor(A$x_1, levels = unique(A$x_1), labels = 1:length(unique(A$x_1)))

y_4 <- factor(A$y_1, levels = unique(A$y_1), labels = 1:length(unique(A$y_1)))

B <- data.frame(y_3, z_1, y_4)
```

I was just wondering if anyone knew of other simpler or more efficient ways of doing this-perhaps using other packages in R. My original data is quite large and efficiency would be crucial here. Also, I haven't quite figured out a way to rename `y_1` into other variables apart from 1s and 2s (for example, I'd prefer `"M"` to be changed into 100 and `"O"` into 101 instead of the 1s and the 2s).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lapply` and subset those columns where we need to change the `index`. In the `A` dataset, we are interested in `x_1` and `y_1` columns. Convert those `columns` to `factor` and then use `as.numeric` which will give the numeric index and then assign those columns.

```
A[,c('x_1','y_1')] <- lapply(A[,c('x_1','y_1')], 
                         function(x) as.numeric(factor(x)))
```

Another option would be to check if the previous values are not equal to the current row values. ie. `x[-1]!= x[-length(x)]`.  Here `x[-1]` removes the first element, likewise, `x[-length(x)]` removes the last element (so that the lengths are the same).  Then use `c(TRUE,..)` to get the length as same as the length of `x` object and do `cumsum`.  This method works if the columns are already ordered.  Otherwise, the `factor` approach is much safer.

```
 A[,c(1,3)] <- lapply(A[,c(1,3)], function(x)
               cumsum(c(TRUE,x[-1]!=x[-length(x)])))
```

To change the index from `1:2` to `100, 101`, you can use the numeric index itself.  Here the `1` values will be replaced by `100` and `2` with `101`.

```
 A[,3] <- c(100,101)[A[,3]]
 A
 #  x_1  z_1 y_1
 #1    1  1.1 100
 #2    1  1.4 100
 #3    1  1.6 100
 #4    2 -1.0 100
 #5    2 -2.2 100
 #6    2  3.0 100
 #7    2  2.3 100
 #8    3  2.0 100
 #9    4 -3.4 101
 #10   4 -4.1 101
 #11   4  2.0 101
 #12   5  2.0 101
 #13   6  2.4 101
 #14   6 -3.5 101
```

Another approach would be to use `Map` considering that we don't want the same index for all the columns.  Here, the `x` values are the columns `x_1`, `y_1` which will be in a list of `2` elements.  Corresponding `y` values will be `1:6` and `c(101, 102)`.  Then use, the same indexing/as.numeric as mentioned above.

```
 A[,c(1,3)] <- Map(function(x, y) y[as.numeric(factor(x))] ,
                            A[,c(1,3)], list(1:6, c(100,101)))
```

Comment: that's a sweet code you have there, works so well and much easier to read and understand. Thanks!

Comment: do you mind explaining the last two codes pls-especially the `cumsum(c(TRUE, x[-1]!=x[-length(x)]))` part. I'm guessing this is saying that the last column should not be treated as a cumulative sum? thanks

Comment: @Thanks so much akrun, the explanation is very clear!